Dealing with online PDF files in Selenium
Following from my previous three questions:
Most pages I scraped lead to PDF files, for speeches done before 2010. I want to use something like tika or pypdf to extract the text from the pages, but first I need to open the files in Python.
Usually, if the site didn't use a javascript barrier, this is what I would do:
import requests
from tika import parser # pip install tika
hdr = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/jose-sarney/discursos/1985/02.pdf'

response = requests.get(url,headers=hdr)
with open('/tmp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)

raw = parser.from_file('/tmp/metadata.pdf')
print(raw['content'])

The way the site is organized, though, makes it impossible to do so.
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
I suppose Selenium's WebDriverWait can help with that. But then what, would I have to download the PDF? Or can I load it to a variable, then extract the text?

I would probably just download the PDF from the site, load it from disk, parse it to get what I needed, close it, and move on.

I would certainly do that, but it's 4500 PDFs with the old speeches and I couldn't get requests to work. Can I use WebDriverWait to download it as a temp file and process each?

I tried using Selenium, requests, and urllib and none of them worked. The problem with Selenium is that when the PDF is loaded in the browser, it's inside an embed tag so the contents are not visible to Selenium. I tried switching into the embed tag like an IFRAME and that didn't work either. The only thing I can think of that would be "easy" would be to set chromedriver options to either autodownload files and/or not allow PDFs to open.

I found this but those options aren't working for me. I get prompted. I tried for a while to find the current chromeoptions but couldn't find an actual list that contained anything to do with downloading files.

One other option you might consider is to uninstall/disable the PDF handler extension/setting in Chrome. That might trigger Chrome to download the PDF instead of opening it in the browser.

It does work, but the PDF files raise a security exception, saying the certificate was issued  for another government website. So, I have to approve each download individually. Is there a way to suspend that?

I have no idea. Sorry.

Nevermind. I definitely can't thank you enough for all your insight this week.
